# How can I make a nice looking house without using A LOT of materials?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Yes, I am a builder, I make nice houses but they take 10 stacks of logs 2 stacks of glass and 5 stacks of cobble, (this is in survival) and friends want me to build them one. How can I make a house without so many materials? They want me to make the EXACT house (no smaller no larger) and mining is a thing that I can't get to.

Comment: Make a smaller house...?

Comment: Let me give you [ALOT](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) [of wood](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bUWDb.jpg)...

Comment: Why can't you mine?

Comment: have them provide the materials...

Comment: Your question: How can I make a house without so many materials? is impossible to answer, given that you want "make the EXACT house". Give us a question that we can give you an answer to.

Answer (score 10):

Here you go:

[image: picture of a Minecraft house]

If it's not exactly what you want, well, I can't really help you, as you say you want something that takes 10 stacks of logs, 2 stacks of glass, and 5 stacks of cobble, but without that requirement, this will do nicely.

Comment: I'm interested to know why the chimney is important?

Comment: It's not, I believe it was a joke.

Answer (score 0):

Have them give you the materials, or if you just want a nice house my favorite way is to build a cobble, wood or brick pyramid with stairs. to do this, get a 10x10or bigger (make sure all 4 sidea are equal, rectangular ones aren't as cool. put stairs on the border excpt the corners, put a layer of something on the inside of those. put a layer of stairs on top of those in the same way. remove the non-stairs and repeat that until you have a 2x2 area left, just seal that off.

Comment: This is a beach house of my own design, and I make the roof in a triangular prism form.The house is 12 X 12 (1 wood 3 glass 1 wood 2 glass 1 wood 3 glass 1 wood - lay blocks in this fashion)